# Identify DBMS from dialect SQL syntax?

Tags: sql

I'm working with a third party API for which I have no documentation. There is a method that takes a SQL string and returns a resultset. Based on valid SQL syntax, I want to identify the SQL DBMS vendor, product and version.

Syntax that works as expected as part of a valid `SELECT` query:

- `CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`
- `CAST('Catatonic' AS CHAR(3))`
- `GETDATE()`
- `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101))`
- `SELECT TOP 1 valid_column FROM ValidTable`

Syntax that causes syntax errors:

- `COALESCE(NULL, 'Dog')`
- `ISNULL(NULL, 'Dog')`
- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
- `SELECT @@VERSION`
- `SELECT version()`
- statements terminated by `;` (though this could be an API thing)

Any other SQL syntax to try?

Comment: don't work on the nitpicky sql syntax, just throw the 'big' dbms versioning queries at the system, like the `select @@version`, e.g. mysql: `select version()`. if you're going to be throwing random queries at the db and expecting most of them to fail, at least throw useful queries that will directly answer things.

Comment: The CONVERT function and SELECT TOP 1 notation are interesting — not wholly standard.    COALESCE is Standard SQL (as in ISO 9075); ISNULL is non-standard but common.  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is Standard SQL.  The @@VERSION is strongly indicative — I believe that notation is used by MS SQL Server and Sybase and I'm not aware of other systems that use it (which isn't the same as no other systems use it).

Comment: This is a hard one.... can't you just ask the 3rd party customer support? everything on the first list will work with any supported version of sql server, but also everything on the second list...

Comment: Looking for the data from the system catalogs for different DBMS can tell you which system you're connected to, if that's what you're trying to discover.

Comment: T-SQL seems most likely, it may be the case that the input expression is filtered/restricted prior to execution, although COALESCE/ISNULL are odd choices to prohibit.

Comment: @MarcB: erm, I already said I tried `SELECT @@VERSION`.

Comment: that's what I'm saying too. issue those specific types of queries, instead of looking for things like `select top`

Comment: @MarcB: can you suggest some please? FWIW the two you name-checked don't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt at an answer, given your tests and the comments above:

Tell the 3rd-party that hosts the API, as well as your boss and/or customer, that you cannot work with an API that does not have documentation, and you MUST have further support from the API vendor to perform your work effectively.

If the documentation says "ANSI SQL Compliant", then that is obviously not true, since your tests include various (well thought-out) instances that would seem to suggest SQL Server, but obviously do not support all queries that SQL Server itself would allow.

So, the 3rd party is apparently filtering, re-parsing, or otherwise modifying the SQL you provide to it, and without further information about what that layer is and what it does/doesn't do, you're hands are more or less tied, and your limited to guesswork and trial-and-error.

Comment: The 3rd party isn't very responsive to my requests for info, especially things that are specific and only a few devs would know. I kinda assumed this info would be 'company confidential' but it's worth a try, I guess!

Comment: If you are a customer, and they are exposing an API for you to use, it is their obligation to give you enough info (documentation) to use the API properly!  Of course, not all vendors are great vendors, but this is the line I would take.